# Account, paid for Apps and new account

Tags: applications, google-account

My children have nexus tablets. They have their own google accounts with email adresses.
My ex-wife has changed the google passwords so i cannot set up a new android phone for the children. If i set up new account/email addresses on the phone or for their tablets, how can I install the paid for apps which are connected with their previous accounts whilst at the same time giving them credit to purchase apps etc on the new accounts?

Any help or advice would be appreciated.
Seamas

Answer (score 1):

Could you ask your ex-wife for the password? That would be the easiest way.

If that doesn't work, you could start a password recovery procedure on a PC, in some cases it uses a registered Android device to verify ownership, which you have access to. Just click on the "I forgot my password" link at [gmail.com](http://www.gmail.com).

Sadly there is no way to transfer paid apps and in-app purchases between Google accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to either get back access to the Google account that was used to buy the apps or buy new copies. It's no different to if you bought software that came on a physical disk and your ex-wife took the disk.